# Storing data from text file to hashmap instead of list

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, storing-data

The following program reads and stores data from a text file of the form

```
1946-01-12;13:00:00;0.3;G
1946-01-12;18:00:00;-2.8;G
1946-01-13;07:00:00;-6.2;G
1946-01-13;13:00:00;-4.7;G
1946-01-13;18:00:00;-4.3;G
1946-01-14;07:00:00;-1.5;G
1946-01-14;13:00:00;-0.2;G
```

to an array list. Then I store the weather object in another class. The first method calculates average temperature between two dates that is user input and the second method calculates the percentage of "G":s between the two dates.

```
/**
 * Provides methods to retrieve temperature data from a weather station file.    
 */
public class WeatherDataHandler {
        private List<Weather> weatherData = new ArrayList<>();

        public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
            List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filepath"));
            for(String str : fileData) {
                List<String> parsed = parseData(str);
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(parsed.get(0));
                    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(parsed.get(1));
                    double temperature = Double.parseDouble(parsed.get(2));
                    String quality = parsed.get(3);
                   
                    Weather weather = new Weather(date, time, temperature, quality);
                    weatherData.add(weather);       
                }
            }
    
            private List<String> parseData(String s) {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split(";"));
            }
        /**
         * Search for average temperature for all dates between the two dates (inclusive).
         * Result is sorted by date.
         */
        public Map<LocalDate, Double> avarageTemperatures(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {
            Map<LocalDate, Double> Averagetemperature = weatherData.stream().filter(weather -> !weather.getDate().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDate().isBefore(dateFrom))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getDate,
                            Collectors.averagingDouble(Weather::getTemperature)));
                    
            return Averagetemperature;}
    
        /**
         * Search for percentage of approved values between the two dates (inclusive).
         */
        public Double approvedValues(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {
            double percentageApproved = weatherData.stream().filter(weather -> !weather.getDate().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDate().isBefore(dateFrom))
                    .mapToInt(obj -> obj.getQuality().equals("G") ? 1 : 0)
                    .summaryStatistics()
                    .getAverage();
            
            return percentageApproved;
        }   
    }
```

Now, instead of implementing maps to the methods I would like to store the data from the file to a hashmap instead of a list (for efficiency). Is there any easy ways to do this without having to redo the methods completely? I tried this:

```
    public class WeatherDataHandler {
        public void loadData1(String filePath) throws IOException {
        List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
        Map<LocalDate, List<Weather>> weatherData = new HashMap<LocalDate,List<Weather>>();{
    for(String str : fileData) {
    List<String> parsed = parseData(str);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(parsed.get(0));
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(parsed.get(1));
    double temperature = Double.parseDouble(parsed.get(2));
    String quality = parsed.get(3);
    Weather weather = new Weather(date,time,temperature,quality);
    
    List<Weather> entries;
    entries = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    if(weatherData.get(date) == null) {
        entries.add(weather);
        weatherData.put(date, entries);
    } else {
        entries = weatherData.get(date);
        entries.add(weather);} 
        }
    }
}
        
        private List<String> parseData(String str) {
            return Arrays.asList(str.split(";"));
        }
```

But how can I access the entries of the map in the methods?

Comment: Hashmap keyed on what? But I'm guessing you would need to change the datatype of "weather" and change weatherData.add(). The rest should be fine.

Comment: I edited the question, so it is keyed on dates, and the value is a list. @JosephLarson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash map will not work for your use case. HashMap helps you find the matching value, given a key. For example, you could make a HashMap that gives you the matching weather data given one date. But, you can't use a HashMap to answer the query "give me all weather data between these two dates" without iterating over the date range. And that's what you need for your `avarageTemperatures` and `approvedValues` methods.

What you could use instead, is `TreeMap`. It will require changing your program in a couple of places.

The variable declaration:

```
private List<Weather> weatherData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Has to become:

```
private NavigableMap<LocalDate, List<Weather>> weatherData = new TreeMap<>();
```

This is a "map from date to list of weather data" because there are more than one  data item per date. If you can change that, it would be simpler.

Next, instead of using `weatherData.add(weather)` you need to use:

```
weatherData.computeIfAbsent(date, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(weather);
```

Again, this is more complicated because there may be more than one item per date.

Lastly, where you access the data through iteration:

```
weatherData.stream().filter(weather -> !weather.getDate().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDate().isBefore(dateFrom))
```

You would leverage the `subMap` method instead, which looks up a key range directly:

```
weatherData.subMap(dateFrom, dateTo).values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the tree map and it seems fine to me, but I am having troubles accessing the data. It says "weatherData cannot be resolved". Did you miss something in "weatherData.subMap(dateFrom, dateTo).values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)"?

Comment: I fixed the error, but my avarageTemperatures method can't find any matching values for provided dates. My tree map looks like this now: [{1946-01-12=[test.Weather@3941a79c, test.Weather@506e1b77], 1946-01-13=[test.Weather@4fca772d, test.Weather@9807454, test.Weather@3d494fbf], 1946-01-14=[test.Weather@1ddc4ec2, test.Weather@133314b, test.Weather@b1bc7ed]... Does it look correct?

Comment: yes that looks right. Does `weatherData.subMap(dateFrom, dateTo)` return a map with the dates that you expect?

Comment: One thing to note about subMap, is that it returns a range with "from" included and "to" **excluded**. There is a variant that lets you specify if you want the bounds included or excluded.

Comment: weatherData.subMap(dateFrom, dateTo) returns a map now, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps work on Key Value pairs. It's not possible for you to simply store in the values through the entire text file without first splitting and then iteratively mapping them together.

Comment: I just edited the question. Could it work with the code that I added and do you know how to reference the entries of the map?